# Graph Request JSONObject object always returning null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am very new to the Facebook development game so please bear with me. I followed the getting started guide on everything to setup the app ( at least I think).

I am trying to do a simple graph request to return info like name of my loggged in user. Below is my code. Everytime I run it the JsonObject returns null, which leads me to believe that I am not connecting. Are their trouble shooting consules or anything on facebooks developer site website that shows requests or that I am connected with the app?

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                        Log.i("joe", "dosent appear to have returned nul...");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call `setGraphPath()` for it, something like that:

```
request.setGraphPath(Constants.YOUR_URL);
```

Comment: what would my url be? please forgive me haha still trying to figure out facebook

Answer (score 0):

looks like your not requesting permissions.  on your facebook login button do this:

```
fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email")); //for example
```